# Rails, Remove NIL attributes from select, Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, null

Everyone, i am new to rails. Thanks in advance for any help.
**Here's where i am:**
The user is trying to create a new "challenge", where i am using a `Select` statement from a list of all instances of other model's attribute.
**For Example:** 
Creating a challenge in which i can select one of the cities of all of the users' cities,
And it works. But since `city` column is not a required attribute for the users, some users have `city` as `nil` (not updated in their profile).

**Observation**:

My select dropdown, shows:
blank
blank
blank
kansas
denver
blank 
boston
and so on...

- How can i remove the blank choices from the dropdown?
- How can i show inside the dropdown, only the valid (non nil) users' cities?

**Here's the select**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.select :challenge_city, User.all.collect{ |n| [n.user_city, n.id] }.insert(0, "Select a city for your challenge") %>
</div>
```

```

Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @misterghost, this implementation seems a little off to me; is it true that you're passing a User's id as a 'challenge_city' to your controller? In order to get the city name that way you'd have to call something like User.find(@challenge.challenge_city).user_city... which is all kinds of confusing.

It seems as though there should be a concept of a 'City' model somewhere (i.e. a User has_one City)

Comment: Thanks GD i think that you are right in the scope thing.

Comment: Thanks GD i think that you are right in the scope thing. It's just that i am not really that far into rails, i haven't noticed how to, now you mention it, seems kind of logical. I expect to better understand it once i start to fiddle with it. Why is it that the other solution isn't right when 'sounds' right (quick fix by npn) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular example should be handled in a scope, something like:

`class User
  scope :with_city, -> { where('user_city IS NOT NULL') }
end`

Then call it with

`User.with_city # => all users which have non-nil cities`

As a side note, this example has too much logic in view code. You should consider extracting that logic into your controller, a decorator, or somewhere else.

In controller: 
`@challenge_options = User.with_city.collect { |n| ... }.insert {...}`

In view: 
`<%= f.select :challenge_city, @challenge_options %>`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gdpelican that your view contains too much logic.  But since you have a column city,  you could/should push this down even further in to the model

You can get all the Users with a particular city via:

```
User.find_all_by_city some_city_name
```

or if you just want a quick fix you can can just "compact" the array returned by your collect block

```
<%= f.select :challenge_city, User.all.collect{ |n| [n.user_city, n.id] if n.user_city }.compact.insert(0, "Select a city for your challenge") %>
```

which will remove the nil elements from your array

Comment: Not sure searching for users by city name is appropriate here, since the OP is looking to select a single city from a list of all possible cities for all users (I think.)

...Actually, looking at this again.. this code will pass a User id under the guise of a 'challenge_city' to the controller, which seems.. er, wrong.